# How do I use an if statement inside an if statement to return a string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private string ffNameProbability()
{
    int rng = rand.Next(6);
    if (rng == 1)
    {
        if (ffAName().Contains('a') == true)
        {
            return ffAName();
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is return ffAName() only if rng ==1 and if ffAName() contains the letter A. Am I missing something really obvious? I'm really new to this.

Comment: Whatever this is, this is not C++.

Comment: When asking questions it helps to tag the right language...

Comment: @SMeaden oops, I guess it is C#. I'm not the sharpest knife in the drawer...

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks. I'm really new to this thing, I appreciate it.

Comment: Your code looks fine, except that it is missing `return` statements for the `else` blocks when the input is NOT what you are expecting: `if (rng == 1) { if (ffAName().Contains('a')) { return ffAName(); } else { return ...; } } else { return ...; }`, or simpler: `if (rng == 1) { if (ffAName().Contains('a')) { return ffAName(); } } return ...;` On the other hand, the two `if` statements can be merged together using the `&&` operator: `if ((rng == 1) && ffAName().Contains('a')) { return ffAName(); } return ...;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ffAName()` is a method that returns a string, the only thing syntactically wrong is that `ffNameProbability()` doesn't return if you don't hit your `if` condition.

So you could do:

```
private string ffNameProbability()
{
    int rng = rand.Next(6);


    if (rng == 1 && ffAName().Contains('a)) //combined these conditions - not necessary, just cleaner (I think)
    {
        return ffAName();
    }

    return null; //only hits if above is false. 
}
```

Which returns either `ffaName()` or `null`, depending on the value of `rng`.

Comment: @MikailKraft You're welcome. If you're learning C#, keep in mind that your methods must always be able to return a value (unless it's `void`). If you use Visual Studio you should get compiler warnings for this.

Comment: @Mikhail: please give levelonehuman points by accepting his/her answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this will check 'A' or 'a'

    if(ffAName().IndexOf("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 && 
rng == 1)
        {
            return ffAName();
        }
```